# Can't get GET HTTP using Node js

Tags: java, android, node.js, server, http-get

It is somthing very weird.

I am using my android device to send messages to my node js server in LAN.

And now here comes the problem: When I send POST HTTP it DOES work. But when I send GET HTTP it DOES NOT work and the server even not recieve the get request.

This is my code for recieving the get:

```
app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook'));
```

And this is the code in androif for sending the GET:

```
 public class Background_confirmation extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

       // progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Confirmation.this, "Please wait...", "Retrieving data ...", true);

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://localhost:8080/auth/facebook");
        // replace with your url

        HttpResponse response = null;
        try {
            response = client.execute(request);

            Log.d("Response of GET request", response.toString());
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        return response.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);


            // progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
      //  }
    }
```

Someone have an idea for why it happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to get the data from `localhost` (i.e., your Android device) instead of from your server.